# Plesk Django .py files showing in browser. How do I make it safe?

Tags: python, django, apache, security, plesk

I create some django websites using Plesk Onyx. My problem is If I go to domainname.com/appname/settings.py or domainname.com/manage.py url i see everything in ".py" file. My folder permissions 755, file permissions is 644. The problem is solved when I set the file permissions to 640 or 600. Is there a shortcut in django related to this vulnerability? or do I need to change individual file permissions? I'm looking for an easy way. I don't know, maybe by adding a little code in django I can prevent these files from appearing. Im using python 3.6 - Django 2.2.3 - Plesk Onyx - Nginx

Comment: You should configure apache/nginx not to serve files in the "application directories"

Comment: Can i do this from in plesk? Can you give me a hint about how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Granted 700 permissions to all folders except media and static folders. and i give 700 permissions manage.py + passenger_wsgi.py file.

Also i add "Additional nginx directives" in plesk

```
location ~* .(py|sqlite3|pyc)$ {
return 404;
}
```

I think its okay and secure now..

Answer (score 1):

in ur .htaccess file **block directory browsing**

1. if want block specific extention

   IndexIgnore *.py *.txt
2. block full directory listing

   Options -Indexes